# Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial with real coefficients such that $f(0) = 1$, $f(2) + f(3) = 125,$ and for all $x$, $f(x)f(2x^2) = f(2x^3 +x)$. Find $f(5)$

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

> Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial with real coefficients such that $f(0) = 1$, $f(2) + f(3) = 125,$ and for all $x$, $f(x)f(2x^2) = f(2x^3 +x)$. Find $f(5)$.

If $r$ is a root of $f$, then $f(r)f(2r^2)=f(2r^3+r)$ and since $f(r)= 0$ we have that $$f(2r^3+r)=0$$ implying that $2r^3+r$ is also a root of $f$.

I cannot get any more information out of the question than this. What kind of considerations I should do here? Is there some general results about polynomials that I could consider such as looking at the degree of $f$ in some way?

Comment: $(x^2+1)^2$ will do.

Comment: And you were on the verge of showing that it has no real roots since if it has one real root, it has infinitely many real roots.

Comment: The leading coefficient of $f$ must be $1$.  And any $f(x)=(x^2+1)^{n}$ satisfies the third condition, but only for $=2$ the other conditions are fulfilled.

Comment: Hence it would be sufficient to show that the only roots of $f$ are $\pm i$.